# Add date/time to uploaded filenames in php

Tags: php, file, date, filenames, overwrite

Is there anyway to add date/time or any other filename-edits that will prevent overwriting in this php code:

```
$name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
```

or this code:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location.$name)) {
    echo 'file uploaded! ';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
<?php
    if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location.time().'_'.$name)) {
        echo 'file uploaded! ';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Oh yes! Thank you so much!!!
Awesome! Too bad my reputation is to low to vote up!

Comment: glad i could help! you could accept it as an answer though

Answer (score 1):

I hope that the family of the patient have been notified!

```
$path=$_FILES['file']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$base = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$name = $base.date("Y-m-d_H_i_s.").$ext;
```

You what you want is to prevent same filename for different files, you can use a hash of the data inside the file instead:

```
$path=$_FILES['file']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$base = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$md5 = md5_file($path);
$name = $base.'_'.$md5.'.'.$ext;
```

You can also combine these:

```
$path=$_FILES['file']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$base = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$md5 = md5_file($path);
$name = $base.'_'date("_Y-m-d_H_i_s.").$md5.$ext;
```

More info here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5-file.php

http://php.net/pathinfo

Comment: @user3332711 if you feel the question was answered, please accept the answer when the time comes, good luck in your coding adventures, php is fun! :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you like to keep the original filename and add e.g. the date at the end?
You'll need to split the filename into name and extension, then add the date to the end of name and glue it all together again

Comment: see example of @DusteD